# Comparing variables from file

Tags: python

*script is in python and it is used to create a file that saves username and password, I understand that there are flaws in the overall script but I want to know:
when script is executed, a username and password is saved into a file separated with ','. each line is a start of a new username. When login function is called, the list is searched and compared with the entered username, after found is positive: password is checked and this is where my script doesn't work as intended.
Why can't I get a positive when comparing 2 variables (for password in login function), they should be identical.(note y, is the line read from file of usernames & passwords, where the first element is username and second password)*

```
def function():

    username=input('enter username')
    password=input('enter password')

    file=open('users1','a')
    file.write(username + ',' + password +'\n')


def login():

    user=input('username')
    passw=input('password')

    file=open('users','r')
    searchline=file.readline()

    for line in file:
        if user in line:
            x=line
            y=x.split(',')
            print(y[1])
            if user == y[1]:
                print('access confirmed')
            else:
                print('pass=', y[1])


function()

login()
```

Comment: You dont seem to write and read the same file

Comment: Also you are comparing `user` with `y[1]` which is the second value (password)

Comment: Your problem is using `file.readline()` - there is a newline at the end of the string which won't be there in the other version of the string.  use: `searchline = file.readline().rstrip()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you writing to and reading from have different names (`users1` and `users`). Each line read from the file has an end of line character (`\n`) need to strip that out before comparing the passwords.

```
def function():

        username = input('enter username')
        password = input('enter password')

        file = open('users','a')
        file.write(username + ',' + password + '\n')


def login():

        username = input('username')
        password = input('password')

        file = open('users','r')

        for line in file:
            if username in line:
                y = line.rstrip().split(',')
                print(y[1])
                if password == y[1]:
                    print('access confirmed')
                else:
                    print('password =', y[1])


function()

login()
```

checkout the python documentation on [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)